# How to access a inner class through an outer class constructor?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a person using the person constructor in my main with the code

```
Person outerClass = new Person("Anon", new Date(06,03,1991), null);
```

but it says that it cannot find the class Date. Am I correctly filling this constructor and calling the interclass right?

```
public class Person implements Cloneable
    {
        private String name;
        private Date born;
        private Date died;//null indicates still alive.

        public Person(String initialName, Date birthDate, Date deathDate)
        {
            if (consistent(birthDate, deathDate))
            {
                name = initialName;
                born = new Date(birthDate);
                if (deathDate == null)
                    died = null;
                else
                    died = new Date(deathDate);
             }
             else
             {
                 System.out.println("Inconsistent dates. Aborting.");
                 System.exit(0);
             }
        }
       private class Date
        {
            private String month;
            private int day;
            private int year; //a four digit number.

            public Date( )
            {
                month = "January";
                day = 1;
                year = 1000;
            }

            public Date(int monthInt, int day, int year)
            {
                setDate(monthInt, day, year);
            }
```

Comment: Why in the name of all things holy would you make Date a private inner class?? Why not simply make it a stand-alone public class (although changing its name to avoid confusion with `java.util.Date`)?

Comment: Thats what I was thinking too but the assignment calls for it :/

Comment: Show the actual full requirements please. You could be misinterpreting them.

Comment: How much do you know about inner classes? An inner class requires an instance of its declaring class. So how are you going to create that `new Date` instance without a reference to the `new Person` instance?

Comment: Redo the class Person so that the class Date is a private innerclass of the class Person. Also, do a suitable test program.

Comment: **Full** requirements

Comment: I'd ignore that instruction. A date does not belong to a person. If it did, two different people couldn't have the same birthday.

Comment: Yea I was very confused by it too, I would make it a separate class but we are on the inner class chapter so I feel that wouldn't make sense either.

Comment: Perhaps they mean it should be an inner static class? This would mean declaring a member of that type. However you would not be able to pass an object of that type to the constructor (obviously, given it's an inner class)

Comment: @sprinter There is no such thing as an _inner static class_. Those terms are contradictory. A _nested class_ is a class that is declared within another class. An _inner class_ is a _nested class_ that is not declared `static`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your requirements call for an inner class, let's set aside the questions about whether or not it is appropriate for `Date` to be an inner class of `Person`.

It cannot find class `Date` because it is private. However, even if it was public, you still would not be able to instantiate one because you would first need an instance of a `Person`. One way to do this is to remove the `Date` parameters from the constructor and use mutators instead. e.g.:

```
public class Person {
    private final String name;
    private Date birthDate;

    public class Date {
        private final int year, month, day;

        public Date(final int year, final int month, final int day) {
            this.year = year;
            this.month = month;
            this.day = day;
        }

        public String toString() {
            // look at me, I can access attributes of the enclosing Person
            return name + " is associated with the year " + year;
        }
    }

    public Person(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(final Date birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public static final void main(final String... arguments) throws Exception {
        final Person person = new Person("name");
        final Date birthDate = person.new Date(2015, 11, 9);
        person.setBirthDate(birthDate);
    }
}
```

However, if it makes sense for the inner class to exist independently of an instance of the outer class, then it should be static. This would allow you to instantiate a `Date` on its own without an existing `Person`. e.g.:

```
public class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final Date birthDate;

    public static class Date {
        private final int year, month, day;

        public Date(final int year, final int month, final int day) {
            this.year = year;
            this.month = month;
            this.day = day;
        }

        public String toString() {
            // I do not know about any Person
            return "year: " + year;
        }
    }

    public Person(final String name, final Date birthDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public static final void main(final String... arguments) throws Exception {
        final Person person = new Person("name", new Date(2015, 11, 9));
    }
}
```

Note, this is functionally the same as declaring `Date` as its own top-level class except that now the full-qualified class name ends with "Person.Date".